# iPhone app crashing on local notification

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios, notifications

This is *weird*. My application schedules local notifications whenever it is sent into the background, and while the first notification is being displayed correctly, as soon as the one after that should be fired, the whole application crashes. Yes, in the background. While no code is being executed.

No console output is given, I just get a dialog box that says "The simulated application quit" in iPhone simulator. On an actual iPhone I get dumped back to the springboard.

Here's the relevant code for the notifications. Thanks for your help.

```
- (void)scheduleLocalNotificationsForAlarmsWithNextAlarmAt:(NSDate *)theFireDate ofType:(int)workPlayType {  

    BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
    UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
        backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
    if(!backgroundSupported) return;

    int work_minutes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"work_minutes_preference"];
    int play_minutes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"play_minutes_preference"];

    int workPlayStatusForNotif = workPlayType;

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;

    if (workPlayStatusForNotif == 1) {
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Work";
        localNotif.repeatInterval = work_minutes;
    } else {
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Play";
        localNotif.repeatInterval = play_minutes;
    }

    localNotif.fireDate = theFireDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);

    localNotif.soundName = @"ding.caf";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

    // now the other one
    localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;

    if (workPlayStatusForNotif == 0) {
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Work";
        localNotif.fireDate = [theFireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(float)work_minutes*60];
        localNotif.repeatInterval = work_minutes;
    } else {
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Play";
        localNotif.fireDate = [theFireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(float)play_minutes*60];
        localNotif.repeatInterval = play_minutes;
    }
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);

    localNotif.soundName = @"ding.caf";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
}
```

Comment: Do a stacktrace with the debugger. Also, what exit status do you get?

Comment: Seems stupid but, how do I do that? It seems all debugging output stops when the app enters the background.

Comment: @winsmith Have your Debugged? What did you got for SIGABRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an iOS 4.1 bug. I have similar problems with my app which used to work with 4.0. Also other people reported problems like that in the apple developer forums. Waiting for an response from apple.

Greetings,

Ben

Comment: Have some more infos about the problem. But in my case it seems that has not to do with local notification, but with CLLocationManager, especially significantLocationChanges.

Comment: I'm using 4.0 at the moment. So this is out.

Answer (score 1):

on which device you are testing on? where do you check if the device is iPhone3G? This code is not going to run on Iphone3g even it is on iOS4 as iPhone3G is not supported multitasking.
Rest of the code looks OK.

Comment: But why is it crashing the debugger then? That one is set to iPhone 4. I'll try anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is an iOS 4.1 issue, I've also faced same kind of issue "Simulator crashed" but I've also experienced another issue that is:
If we fire more-than one Local-Notification in the background, then it also crashed iPhone iOS :S

I'm unable to find any workaround to execute more-than one Local Notification. Apple Development team must have to validate Local-Notification deeply.